# Should implicit reference be preferred over explicit

Tags: java, reference

For example, in the function below, which adds a node to BST, I have used only implicit references.
I could have declared explicitly a variable TreenNode node = .., at start of function and used it where appropriate. Now, I am not aware if it is opinion based or not. Sincerely is there any pros or or con of using OPTION1 over OPTION2

OPTION1:

```
 public void add(int item) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(null, item, null);
            return;
        }

        TreeNode node = root;
        while (true) {
            if (item < node.item) {
                if (node.left == null) {
                    node.left = new TreeNode(null, item, null);
                    break;
                }
                node = node.left;
            } else {
                if (node.right == null) {
                    node.right = new TreeNode(null, item, null);
                    break;
                }
                node = node.right;
            }
        }
    }
```

OPTION 2:

```
public void add(int item) {

            TreeNode nodeNew = new TreeNode(null, item, null); // explicit

            if (root == null) {
                root = nodeNew;
                return;
            }

            TreeNode node = root;
            while (true) {
                if (item < node.item) {
                    if (node.left == null) {
                        node.left = nodeNew;
                        break;
                    }
                    node = node.left;
                } else {
                    if (node.right == null) {
                        node.right = nodeNew;
                        break;
                    }
                    node = node.right;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: function should add a node to BST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is more optimizied as it involves less steps.
Option 2 means you create a variable holding a reference to only use it to assign - it only may look better for some people. In option 1 you skip the temporary reference and make the assignment and object creation directly.

At the end of the day however, there isn't another difference.

---

Also, in option 2 it is better to move your declaration of nodeNew below the return.

Why initialize something if you won't use it.

```
            if (root == null) {
                root = node;
                return;
            }

TreeNode nodeNew = new TreeNode(null, item, null); // explicit
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think the line `root = node;` in option 2, you probably intend it to be: `root = nodeNew;`, do you?

There is a potential benefit I think, in that everywhere that `nodeNew` is referenced in option2, it's within a conditional, so it may never be used. In this case, option1 has the advantage of only instantiating a new `TreeNode` object when it's needed.
In this particular case though, it looks like each call to this `add` method will always need to create a new `TreeNode` -- if not in the initial condition, then at some iteration of the while loop; so in this case there isn't really an efficiency benefit that I can see in that respect.

One aspect of this that might be worth thinking about (and talking to other people who may work on your code also), is the maintainability of it. I see a potential advantage and a potential disadvantage to option1 in this case. Maybe these situations don't apply to the specific example that you've given, but may to others that this question applies to:

**Potential advantage:**

If this is a long section of code, it's always clear at all of the points where a new TreeNode is being created, that it is in fact a TreeNode object that's being created (and not, say, some derivative), and what parameters were passed to its constructor.

**Potential disadvantage:**

If it will never be subclassed, and all instantiations in this method will be given the exact same parameters, then option2 has the benefit of having one place where a change needs to be made (change one of the parameters for example).